# Why does my Scala future not propagate an Error?

Tags: scala, exception, error-handling, future

This code works as expected:

```
it("should propagate exceptions") {
  intercept[RuntimeException] {
    val future = Future { Thread.sleep(10); sys.error("whoops"); 22 }
    Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
  }.getMessage should equal ("whoops")
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
it("should propagate errors") {
  intercept[StackOverflowError] {
    val future = Future { Thread.sleep(10); throw new StackOverflowError("dang"); 22 }
    Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
  }.getMessage should equal ("dang")
}
```

The future in this second test never returns. Why doesn't an `Error` subclass (as opposed to an `Exception` subclass) terminate my future? How should I handle `Error`s?

EDIT: This is possibly related, but not identical, to [Why does Scala Try not catching java.lang.StackOverflowError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38053222/why-does-scala-try-not-catching-java-lang-stackoverflowerror). I'm not using `Try` here. The core issue is that the `Future` never returns at all; I can't catch any error from it because it just hangs.

Comment: Probably related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38053222/why-does-scala-try-not-catching-java-lang-stackoverflowerror/38053328

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Scala Try not catching java.lang.StackOverflowError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38053222/why-does-scala-try-not-catching-java-lang-stackoverflowerror)

Answer (score 1):

The `reporter` facility is for catastrophes, which just hooks into the thread's `UncaughtExceptionHandler`, but it looks like it works out of the box with just the default thread factory:

```
scala 2.13.0-M5> import concurrent._,java.util.concurrent.Executors
import concurrent._
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

scala 2.13.0-M5> val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(null, e => println(s"Handle: $e"))
ec: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContextExecutor = scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$3@5e7c141d[Running, parallelism = 4, size = 0, active = 0, running = 0, steals = 0, tasks = 0, submissions = 0]

scala 2.13.0-M5> val f = Future[Int](throw new NullPointerException)(ec)
f: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Future(<not completed>)

scala 2.13.0-M5> f
res0: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Future(Failure(java.lang.NullPointerException))

scala 2.13.0-M5> val f = Future[Int](throw new StackOverflowError)(ec)
Handle: java.lang.StackOverflowError
f: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Future(<not completed>)
```

whereas

```
scala 2.13.0-M5> val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor, e => println(s"Handle: $e"))
ec: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContextExecutor = scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl@317a118b

scala 2.13.0-M5> val f = Future[Int](throw new StackOverflowError)(ec)
f: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Future(<not completed>)
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$.$anonfun$f$1(<console>:1)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)
    at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:261)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:209)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.doMap(Promise.scala:420)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.run(Promise.scala:402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

You could construct a rig that registers a future when it runs, and a safe await that knows when threads have blown up. Maybe you want to retry an algorithm with a lower max recursion depth, for example.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, this is a duplicate of [Why does Scala Try not catching java.lang.StackOverflowError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38053222/why-does-scala-try-not-catching-java-lang-stackoverflowerror)

> According to Scala documentation.
>
> Note: only non-fatal exceptions are caught by the combinators on Try (see >scala.util.control.NonFatal). Serious system errors, on the other hand, will be >thrown.
>
> No Throwable -> Errors are catched by Try

Also to answer your question about how error handling is usually done.
In Scala you can use try / catch for code that can cause exceptions (very similar to Java):

```
try { 
// ... Your dangerous code in here
} catch {
 case ioe: IOException => ... //
 case e: Exception => ...
}
```

And you should always have the more specific exceptions first.

The code you provided would look something like this:
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/2DJXJ6ESS9ySJZSwSodmZg

Also I tried out your code and it definitely produces the StackOverFlowerror.
But it can't catch it properly like the above mentioned link explains.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "it produces the StackOverflowError" -- when I run it, the future never returns. The test just hangs. I'm wondering if it's a version issue -- I'm on 2.11.8 (and can't upgrade at the moment).

Comment: @Sasgorilla If you click the link, you can run the code there. It will display the error in the console. The error can't be caught. If you check the duplicate question, the answer is that you need the Try to be able to catch it. Makes sense?

Comment: Apologies -- I'm not quite following the `try` thing. In your fiddle I still see the `Await` timing out after 30 seconds. In other words, I'm catching a `TimeoutException`, not the `StackOverflowError`. Could you share an example using `try` where the `StackOverflowError` is propagated?